# How to trigger an sending email to human using Dialogflow ES Fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, nodemailer, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using the fulfillment and nodemailer in my editor and would like to send an email to my personal email address. When I try to integrate to Dialogflow Messenger Beta version, my chatbot will not understand the response.

My output:

```
User: "I would like to send an email to the support service."
Bot: "Sorry. I do not understand your question."
```

Correct output:

```
 User: "I would like to send an email to the support service."
 Bot: "What is your name?"
 User: "Henry"
 Bot: "What is your email?"
 User: "henry65@gmail.com"
 Bot: "Thanks Henry. We will get back to you as soon as possible."
```

index.js

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'james641@gmail.com',
        pass: 'test@1567'
    }
});

 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  
  function sendEmailHandler(agent){
     const { email, name } = agent.parameters;
     const question = agent.parameters.question;
     const mailOptions = {
           from: "James", // sender address
           to: email, // list of receivers
           subject: "Email from Chatbot", // Subject line
           html: "<p>Name:</p> " + name + "<p>Email:</p>" + email + "<p>Questions:</p>" + question
     };
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
           if(err)
           {
               console.log(err);
           }
    });
  }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
  //   agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
  //   agent.add(new Card({
  //       title: `Title: this is a card title`,
  //       imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
  //       text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
  //       buttonText: 'This is a button',
  //       buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
  //     })
  //   );
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
  //   agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
  // }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own Google Assistant intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
  //   let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conv instance
  //   conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!') // Use Actions on Google library
  //   agent.add(conv); // Add Actions on Google library responses to your agent's response
  // }
  // // See https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-actions-library-nodejs
  // // for a complete Dialogflow fulfillment library Actions on Google client library v2 integration sample

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('sendEmail_intent', sendEmailHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I'm still new to Dialogflow so I'm not that savvy with the webhooks and fulfillments. Please help me.

Comment: Can you update your question to show a screen shot of how you have configured the `sendEmail_intent` Intent? The problem you're describing sounds like it is a problem matching the Intent correctly.

Comment: Check your intent action & parameter value whether they are set correctly with '$' symbol. Did you add "I would like to send an email to the support service" to your Training Phrases ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieving your use case is to activate the Default fallback intent and enable the Fulfilment of that intent. However, you must ensure that you collect the email address at the fallback intent.

- On Dialogflow webhook is triggered by the default fallback, which provides the question
  and sessionID, which is then saved in a database.
- Then fallback method requests an email address.
- Lastly, the user provides an email and intent fires another webhook, which updates the
  original record with the email address and sends the request to the inbox.

To avoid this hassle, you can integrate Dialoglfow with any third-party platform, such as [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/home), and send email notifications directly from the dashboard. When the default fallback intent gets triggered or when a human agent is assigned to a conversation, an email will be automatically sent.

PS: I work for Kommunicate.

Comment: For some reason, I did not receive the user's email address on my personal email.